# gzip extract to get a xml, but the response is strange characters

Tags: php, xml, gzip

I have this code, to get and xml from a gzip.
I´ll updated the entire code.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, XML_PAYLOAD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:     text/xml','Connection: close'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
  $result = 'cURL ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
  log_cron('ERRO', $result, $mid, 'ACESSO AO WEBSERVICE');
} else {
  $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  switch($returnCode) {
    case 200:
      break;
    default:
      $result = 'HTTP ERROR -> ' . $returnCode;
      log_cron('ERRO', $result, $mid, 'ACESSO AO WEBSERVICE');
      break;
  }
}

curl_close($ch);


$arquivo = getZip($result);  
try {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($arquivo);
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Bad xml: ".$e->getMessage();
}


function getZip($stream) {
   $fp = fopen("arquivo.gz", "w");
   fwrite($fp, $stream, 2048);
   fclose($fp);
   sleep(2);
   $zp = gzopen("arquivo.gz", "r");
   $contents = gzread($zp, 10000);
   gzclose($zp);
   return $contents;
}
```

But, even when I extract or try read byte to byte, the response is always the same.

Can someone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6OU5.png)

Comment: Shouldn't `curl_setopt($curl,` be `curl_setopt($ch,`

Comment: How about executing the request (`curl_exec()`)?

Comment: You sure that's been deflated? That image looks like the *"garbage"* you'd get when opening a ZIP file in Notepad++

Comment: Exactly, but i´m in difficult  to deflate, cause always return that garbage.

Comment: Would you be better off not specifying the number of bytes to write (`fwrite($fp, $stream, 2048);`), 2048 seems quite a small number.

Comment: I tried to not specify the bytes, but the response is the same. I think i´m not really descompressing the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
```

should be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
```

Comment: Tks, but, i´l change that, i just put the wrong image here.